# how can we add logo and navbar section in slider js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

Created the slider with swiper js but when I added the logo and the new section it went under the slider, how can I  make the logo visible on the slider.

I added the swiper-mousewheel-control demo from swiper js, after that the logo was hidden behind the slider I want the logo on the slider which will be always visible on the homepage

Comment: _push_ logo by `z-index` on the top...